# Accessig VB Editor in Excel Using Python

Tags: python, excel, vba

Is there a way to access the vb editor in excel(2007) in an existing workbook using python instead of declaring an instance of Excel and creating the workbook in memory like this:

```
import win32com.client as win32

import comtypes, comtypes.client

xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Visible = True
ss = xl.Workbooks.Add()
sh = ss.ActiveSheet

xlmodule = ss.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)  # vbext_ct_StdModule

sCode = '''sub VBAMacro()
       msgbox "VBA Macro called"
      end sub'''

xlmodule.CodeModule.AddFromString(sCode)
```

Comment: Is `ss = xl.Workbooks.Item(1)` (or iterating through them to find the one with the right name, or whatever) not what you want here?

Comment: I want to open a workbook on disc and add a subroutine to the VBA editor instead of creating the workbook in memory.

Comment: `ss = xl.Workbooks.Open(wbPathHere)`

Answer (score 0):

The only reason you're creating a new workbook is that you're explicitly asking Excel to do so. This line:

```
ss = xl.Workbooks.Add()
```

… is calling the `Add` method of the `Workbooks` object. As [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff841074.aspx) says, and as you'd expect from the name, this:

> Creates a new workbook. The new workbook becomes the active workbook. Returns a `Workbook` object.

---

What if you want to access an existing one? Like every other collection, `Workbooks` has `Count` and `Item`:

> Returns the number of objects in the collection.
>
> Returns a single object from a collection.

So, you can get the first existing workbook, or you can iterate through all of them to find the one whose name you want, or… whatever seems appropriate.

---

What if you want to open a file on disk and access that workbook? `Workbooks` also has `Open`:

> Opens a workbook.

---

If it's not clear how to use these methods, click on them in the documentation, and they give you the full signature and a complete description of what they do. For example, [`Open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff194819.aspx) looks like:

```
expression.Open(FileName, UpdateLinks, ReadOnly, Format, Password, WriteResPassword, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended, Origin, Delimiter, Editable, Notify, Converter, AddToMru, Local, CorruptLoad)
```

From the chart below, you can see that all of those arguments are optional. Most likely the only one you want to give it is `FileName`.